# javascript using map,filter or find get this

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Here is the Example:
My first array:

```
var array1= [
{"dt":"20:25","al":"my test","totalprice":4180,"curr":"INR","duration":"0:00:00","dates":"2020-12-10"},
{"dt":"22:45","al":"my test","totalprice":4180,"curr":"INR","duration":"0:00:00","dates":"2020-12-10"},
{"dt":"19:15","al":"my test","totalprice":6043,"curr":"INR","duration":"0:00:00","dates":"2020-12-12"}]
```

Second array:

```
var array2 = [
{
    date: '2020-12-10',
    al: 'my test',
    totalprice: null,
    curr: null,
    dt: null,
    duration: null
    },
{
    date: '2020-12-11',
    al: 'my test',
    totalprice: null,
    curr: null,
    dt: null,
    duration: null
    },
{
    date: '2020-12-12',
    al: 'my test',
    totalprice: null,
    curr: null,
    dt: null,
    duration: null
    }
```

]

I want the array2 of date match with array1 and add all the respective objects of array1 with the matching dates as result and for non-matched dates, the array2 objects must be used.
The date 2020-12-11 has been used from array2 as null since we don't have the date in array1, and other dates are as on array1.

My code:

```
finalresult = array2.map(item => item ? {...item, ...array1.filter(mrd=> mrd.dates === item.date) }: {})
console.log(finalresult)
```

result:

```
[
{
'0': {
  dt: '20:25',
  al: 'my test',
  totalprice: 4180,
  curr: 'INR',
  duration: '0:00:00',
  dates: '2020-12-10'
},
'1': {
  dt: '22:45',
  al: 'my test',
  totalprice: 4180,
  curr: 'INR',
  duration: '0:00:00',
  dates: '2020-12-10'
},
date: '2020-12-10',
al: 'my test',
totalprice: null,
curr: null,
dt: null,
duration: null
},
{
date: '2020-12-11',
al: 'my test',
totalprice: null,
curr: null,
dt: null,
duration: null
},
{
'0': {
  dt: '19:15',
  al: 'my test',
  totalprice: 6043,
  curr: 'INR',
  duration: '0:00:00',
  dates: '2020-12-12'
},
date: '2020-12-12',
al: 'my test',
totalprice: null,
curr: null,
dt: null,
duration: null
}
]
```

I need the result like:

```
[{
  dt: '20:25',
  al: 'my test',
  totalprice: 4180,
  curr: 'INR',
  duration: '0:00:00',
  dates: '2020-12-10'
 },
 {
  dt: '22:45',
  al: 'my test',
  totalprice: 4180,
  curr: 'INR',
  duration: '0:00:00',
  dates: '2020-12-10'
 },
 {
 date: '2020-12-11',
 al: 'my test',
 totalprice: null,
 curr: null,
 dt: null,
 duration: null
 },
 {
  dt: '19:15',
  al: 'my test',
  totalprice: 6043,
  curr: 'INR',
  duration: '0:00:00',
  dates: '2020-12-12'
 }]
```

Can anyone help me out to resolve this

Comment: What does your current code return?

Comment: It adds array2 objects with all the iterations. But I need only when the array2 dates are not in array1. and it returns the filter with key values.

Comment: `{ ...item, ...array1.filter(...) } ` You are spreading an array inside an object literal. This will create an object properties of item and numeric indexes of the array returned by `filter`

Comment: any other possibilities to get it over.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I have added my respone.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [
    {
        dt: '20:25',
        al: 'my test',
        totalprice: 4180,
        curr: 'INR',
        duration: '0:00:00',
        dates: '2020-12-10',
    },
    {
        dt: '22:45',
        al: 'my test',
        totalprice: 4180,
        curr: 'INR',
        duration: '0:00:00',
        dates: '2020-12-10',
    },
    {
        dt: '19:15',
        al: 'my test',
        totalprice: 6043,
        curr: 'INR',
        duration: '0:00:00',
        dates: '2020-12-12',
    },
];

var array2 = [
    {
        date: '2020-12-10',
        al: 'my test',
        totalprice: null,
        curr: null,
        dt: null,
        duration: null,
    },
    {
        date: '2020-12-11',
        al: 'my test',
        totalprice: null,
        curr: null,
        dt: null,
        duration: null,
    },
    {
        date: '2020-12-12',
        al: 'my test',
        totalprice: null,
        curr: null,
        dt: null,
        duration: null,
    },
];

const mapped = array2.reduce((result, item) => {
    const matchedDataArr = array1.filter((data) => data.dates === item.date);

    if (matchedDataArr.length) {
        const itemsToAdd = matchedDataArr.map((matchedData) => {
            const { date, ...rest } = item;

            return {
                ...rest,
                ...matchedData,
            };
        });

        return [...result, ...itemsToAdd]
    }

    return [...result, item];
}, []);

console.log('- result -', mapped);
```